# Float rounding error with Numpy isin function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, floating-point

I'm trying to use the `isin()` function from Numpy library to find elements that are common in two arrays.

Seems pretty basic, but one of those arrays is created using `linspace()` and the other I just put hard values in.

But it seems like `isin()` is using `==` for its comparisons, and so the result returned by the method is missing one of the numbers.

Is there a way I can work around this, either by defining my arrays differently or by using a method other than `isin()` ?

```py
thetas = np.array(np.linspace(.25, .50, 51))
known_thetas = [.3, .35, .39, .41, .45]
unknown_thetas = thetas[np.isin(thetas, known_thetas, assume_unique = True, invert = True)]
```

Printing the three arrays, I find that `.41` is still in the third array, because when printing them one by one, my value in the first array is actually `0.41000000000000003`, which means `==` comparison returns `False`. What is the best way of working around this ?

Comment: Try `numpy.isclose`?

Comment: How do I use it with isin() ?

Comment: What about rounding the numbers in both of your arrays to the second digit after the decimal point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could make use of [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) after extending one of those arrays to `2D` for an outer isclose-match-finding and then doing a `ANY` match to give us a 1D boolean-array that could be used to mask the relevant input array -

```
thetas[~np.isclose(thetas[:,None],known_thetas).any(1)]
```

To customize the level of tolerance for matches, we could feed in custom relative and absolute tolerance values to `np.isclose`.

If you are looking for performance on large arrays, we could optimize on memory and hence performance too with a [NumPy implementation of `np.isin` with tolerance arg for floating pt numbers with `np.searchsorted`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51747164/) -

```
thetas[~isin_tolerance(thetas,known_thetas,tol=0.001)]
```

Feed in your tolerance value in `tol` arg.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed absolute tolerance, you can use [np.around](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) to round the values before comparing:

```py
unknown_thetas = thetas[np.isin(np.around(thetas, 5), known_thetas, assume_unique = True, invert = True)]
```

This rounds `thetas` to 5 decimal digits, but it's up to you to decide how close the numbers need to be for you to consider them equal.