# Find the missing starting number of shuffled cumsum series

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

1. `a` and `b` are two arrays of `floats` of length `n` each. `a` can have both negative and positive entries.
2. `b` is cumulative sum of `a`.
3. `b[0]` != `a[0]`. In fact, `b[0]` = `a[0] + k`
4. Both `a` and `b` are shuffled such that the relative order between them is maintained, i.e., if say `a[0]` becomes `a[6]` then `b[0]` will become `b[6]` and so on.
   **Can someone suggest an algo to find `k` for randomly shuffled `a` and `b` such that their relative order is maintained.**

My naive attempt below (which **takes forever for n>=10**)

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
def get_starting_point(a, b):
    for msk in itertools.permutations(range(len(a))): # NOTE: Takes forever for n>=10.
        new_a = a[list(msk)]
        new_b = b[list(msk)]
        k = new_b[0] - new_a[0]
        new_a = np.cumsum(new_a) + k
        if np.nansum(np.abs(new_b - new_a)) < 0.001:
            return k
    return None
```

Generate samples of `a`, `b` and expected `k` to try your solution:

```
def get_a_b_k(n=14):
    a = np.round(np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=(n,)), 2)
    b = np.cumsum(a)
    prob = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    if prob < 0.4:
        k = np.round(np.random.uniform(-10,10), 2)
    # NOTE: this elif can be removed as its just sub-case of else block.
    elif prob < 0.6:  # k same as the last b.
        k = b[n-1]
        a[n-2] -= k
    else:             # k same as one of b's
        idx = np.random.choice(n, size=1)
        k = b[idx]
        a[idx] -= k
    b = np.cumsum(a)
    msk = np.random.choice(n, size=n, replace=False) # Randomly generated mask of size n.
    return a[msk], b[msk] + k, k
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 find k. my `get_starting_point(a, b)` fails for arrays sized >=10

Comment: Do you mean that `b = np.cumsum(a)+k`?

Comment: @mozway yes exactly that is another way to say the same thing.

Comment: Can `a` have negative numbers?

Comment: @Dave yes it can have any floats except zero. If `a` is not negative then its simple `k = np.max(b) - np.sum(a)`

Answer (score 0):

We have:

```
b = np.cumsum(a) + k
```

We can compute `b-a` to get the previous elements of the sum. Thus the only element of `b-a` that does not belong to `b` indicates the position of the start.

As we are working with floating point numbers, we need a function to match floating point values. I used `isin_tolerance` that is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51747164/16343464).

```
def solve(a, b):
    m = isin_tolerance(b-a, b, 1e-8)
    return (b[~m] - a[~m])[0]

np.random.seed(0)
for i in range(1_000_000):
    a, b, k = get_a_b_k()
    assert np.isclose(k, solve(a, b))
```

This takes a few minutes to run on 1M attempts but did not fail. On 10k tests with `n=200` this runs in ~2s.

*NB. This could fail if coincidentally, `k` is equal to one of the values in `b`, but this is fairly unlikely and did not happen in my random tests.*

Comment: this is a neat solution. However, in my actual dataset the probability of `k=b[i]` is reasonably high.

Comment: Maybe you want to give more details on the background? (Is this an assignment or for a real use case?). You can also provide a better generator of sample data to have a more representative example. I'll have another look tomorrow (if `k` is in `b` there might still be ways to recover it with some extra work).

Comment: this is a real use case from analysing user income/spend data. Here `a` is each entry with `+` for income `-` for spend. `b` is net user balance. I don't get data from the beginning but from some point in time. And I need to infer opening balance, i.e., `k`

Comment: But why is the data randomly ordered? Can't you ensure having a few successive data points?

Comment: This is the error from the source of data (externally sourced) and unfortunately not much can be done. I can think of scenarios where the account ledger is written by more than 1 source.

Comment: I have now modified `get_a_b_k()` to generate sample data where `k=b[i]` with probability 0.5

Comment: Above edge case can further be split into **(1)** `k=b[n-1]` and **(2)** `k=b[i]` where `i` is unshuffled index s.t. `0<=i<n-1`. To rule out **#1**, first check `if np.sum(a) = 0` then return `k` based on my iterative solution (**sub-optimal and non-unique solution**) - in this case I will look to next set of transactions. Then to deal with **#2** (along with `k != b[i]` for any `0<=i<n`) your algo could be modified to search and remove each element of `b` from `b-a` (if present). Whatever is left in `b-a` is returned as `k`.